# Client-side validation difference between Html.TextBoxFor/Html.TextAreaFor and Html.EditorFor (with [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)])

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, client-side-validation, unobtrusive-validation

I am using client-side validation (unobtrusive) in ASP.NET MVC 3/Razor and I got it to work on a `<textarea>` by using Html.EditorFor and specifying DataType.MultilineText, but should not Html.TextAreaFor also have client-side validation?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Foo")]
public string Message { get; set; }

// Does add client-side validation
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message)

// Does NOT add client-side validation
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message)
```

---

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Foo")]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Message { get; set; }

// Does add client-side validation (and multiline)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Message)

// Does NOT add client-side validation
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message)
```

---

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Your example above works fine for me. I wonder - was this a precise example, or was it simplified from a real world problem? I have found this exact behavior when using a model with nested properties.

So, for example, if I change your model to look like this:

```
public class MyModelObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Foo")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public MyModelObject MyObject { get; set; }
}
```

Then I reproduce the exact problem you mentioned.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyObject.Message)
```

generates the jquery validation attributes as expected:

```
<textarea class="text-box multi-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="Foo" id="MyObject_Message" name="MyObject.Message"></textarea>
```

But, this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.MyObject.Message)
```

Does not:

```
<textarea cols="20" id="MyObject_Message" name="MyObject.Message" rows="2"></textarea>
```

If this does in fact describe your issue, it looks like this has been reported as a bug:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8576

Answer (score 0):

As **obliojoe** suggested in his answer, this bug appears when the expression is more complex than a simple property reference.

I have implemented replacement helpers that work around this problem. The trick is to obtain correct model metadata, pass it to `HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` and then pass the received attributes to the original `TextAreaFor()` helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextAreaWithValidationFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var modelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    IDictionary<string, object> validationAttributes = helper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, modelMetadata);
    return TextAreaExtensions.TextAreaFor(helper, expression, validationAttributes);
}
```

I attached a more developed version (which provides all `TextAreaFor` overloads, including those with `htmlAttributes`) of this code to the [bug reported on CodePlex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8576).